# Changed elastic IP and now the same link redirects to different Amazon instances

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, dns, ip

I am running 3 Amazon instances.
Two of them are the free ones, type `t1.Micro`.

And the other one is a `m1.small` instance.

**I had my website running on one of the `t1.Micro` instances** and decided to change today to the `m1.small` one.

Since I bought my domain with goDaddy this is what I did:

- I opened my Amazon console and allocated a new IP address to my  m1.small instance
- Then I opened my goDaddy account and **changed the old elastic IP for the new one** (In the table where it says "A (Host)", find the entry where Host = "@")

The problem is that now every time I click on my website's link **I get redirected to the new** `m1.small` instance (which is good, that is what should happen, but a friend of mine, accessing the same link gets redirected to the old instance.

Why is this? I also found I get redirected to one or another instance if i type the link like this '`www.myaddress.com`' instead of like this '`myaddress.com`'

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Probably your friend's local DNS cache hasn't expired the old GoDaddy records yet? Why are you changing IPs anyway, you could just assign the same IP to the new instance?

Comment: True, didn't think of that! Also I didn't know my friend has a local DNS cache...

Comment: Your friend most likely has a local DNS cache, not necessarily on his own machine, more likely at his ISP. It is _local_ meaning it is close to him (low latency), not that he is running it personally.

Comment: My friend is actually in my house, we are connecting with the same IP and the same ISP :S

Comment: Are the two of you using the same browser? His browser might be caching the DNS records, try closing and reopening it. Most likely this problem with resolve by itself as the record expires in whichever cache seems to be holding on to the old IP.

Comment: Another option is that it is just the OS which caches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from your **browser** caching the records, the **operating system** caches them, and any upstream **DNS** servers too. This happens for up to the "Time To Live" value of the previous DNS record. Changing elastic IP is almost instantaneous compared to this, in my tests the elastic IP continues to be routed to the old instance for about 10 seconds after disassociate/associate, then be unavailable for 10 seconds, after which it would be routed to the new instance.

Instead of relying on GoDaddy and their DNS servers, I propose that you use the excellent Amazon Route53 DNS service instead. It also plays nicely with loadbalancers and other such addiotional stuff. That is, you first register myaddress.com in Route 53, get a list of 4 nameservers from Amazon, then configure as the nameservers in GoDaddy.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the DNS cache (which will expire in a few hours), you should really make www.yourdomain.com an alias for yourdomain.com. Initially, they've most likely been two separate A records pointing at the same IP address and now it's only one that's changed.